# Dynamic Data Display with multiple Y-axis

Tags: c#, wpf, charts

I have to show several line graphs in one plot. As the Y range values differ a lot I want to assign each line a specific y-axis. I already found out that I can do this by using InjectionPlooter and assign the line graphs to them, but the scale of each y-axis is the same.

I'm using an ObservableDataSource for my values.

My XAML-Code:

```
<d3:ChartPlotter x:Name="Plotter" Height="400" Grid.Row="1">
    <d3:InjectedPlotter Name="y2" Background="Aqua">
        <d3:VerticalAxis Placement="Left"/>
        <d3:VerticalAxisTitle Content="y2" Placement="Left" />
    </d3:InjectedPlotter>
    <d3:InjectedPlotter Name="y3" Background="Aqua">
        <d3:VerticalAxis Placement="Left"/>
        <d3:VerticalAxisTitle Content="y3" Placement="Left"/>
    </d3:InjectedPlotter>
    <d3:InjectedPlotter Name="y4" Background="Aqua">
        <d3:VerticalAxis Placement="Left"/>
        <d3:VerticalAxisTitle Content="y4" Placement="Left"/>
    </d3:InjectedPlotter>
</d3:ChartPlotter>
```

My Code behind for one line graph added to the y2-plotter

```
var data = new ObservableDataSource<Point>();

for (int i = 0; i < xvalues.Count(); i++)
{
data.Collection.Add(new Point(Convert.ToDouble(xvalues[i].Replace('.', ','), new CultureInfo("de-DE")) + xoffset, Convert.ToDouble(yaxes4Values[i].Replace('.', ','), new CultureInfo("de-DE"))));
}

LineGraph line = new LineGraph(data);
this.y2.Children.Add(line);
```

Image: [Several line graphs with 4 y-axes](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SHKqV.png)

I really hope someone can help me to scale the Y-Axis because some of the line graphs are only shown as horizontal line and not as a graph over the whole height.

Greetings, 
Caipigott

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i finally found the solution. I figured out that the d3 version i'm using is the V0.4 which is the new Future of DynamicDataDisplay project ([d3future](https://d3future.codeplex.com/)). Inside the D3.Current solution is a very good sample called TwoIndependentAxes.

Greetings,
Caipigott